# Invoking Postresql function from java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a small utility written in java which takes chunk of records from Postgresql database and puts them in Solr.

After indexing in Solr records have to be marked as indexed in Postgresql.
For this purpose I take a Postgresql procedure and pass into it array of records' primary keys.

This is snippet of java procedure for marking:

```
    private void IndexDocumentsAndMark() throws SolrServerException, IOException, SQLException {
    logger.debug("Indexing start execution ...");
    UpdateResponse resp = solrClient.add(documents, solrCommitTimeOut);
    if (resp.getStatus() != 0) {
        logger.error("Indexing error: " + resp.getStatus());
    } else {
        logger.debug("Indexing completed. Indexed " + documents.size() + " documents ...");
        logger.debug("Solr commit start execution ...");
        solrClient.commit(); // Needs to be done in every bulk
        logger.debug("Solr commit completed ...");
        // Mark data in Postgresql as completed if bulk indexed successfully and Postgresql procedure for marking in defined
        if (databaseQueryStringMark != null) {
    // Prepare statement
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(databaseQueryStringMark);
    // Prepare parameters (primary keys)
            java.sql.Array array = con.createArrayOf("integer", paramsArray.toArray());
            pstmt.setArray(1, array);
            logger.debug("Query for mark bulk data as completed start execution ...");
    // Execute procedure
            pstmt.executeQuery();
            logger.debug("Query for mark bulk data as completed execution completed ...");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this stuff is:

If there is no high load on Postgresql server, utility works fine and there is no problem.

However whith high load on Postgresql, server marking procedure (Postgresql procedure) works long enough (about two hours). After marking process (finishing Postgresql procedure) I can see that my java process in memory. It didn't terminate.

The code of Postgresql function is

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION affiliates_service_json_data_mark("id$arr" integer[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
begin
  update solr_interface.affiliates_json_data
  set is_transfered_to_solr = true
  where id in (select unnest(id$arr)
               );
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION affiliates_service_json_data_mark(integer[])
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Could you suggest me where is the source of this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain "*marking process/procedure*"? Does the PostgreSQL query finish (look at `pg_stat_activity`)? Can you take a stack trace from the running java process and figure out where it is? If the problem arises only if there are concurrent transactions, it probably is connected to locking problems.

Comment: What is your `databaseQueryStringMark` and size of `paramsArray` for a typical update?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe _Marking process/procedure_ is invocation Postgresql function from java. Yes, after some time I didn't see Postgresql function in `pg_stat_activity`. There were no concurrent transactions during marking procedure process. I have been monitoring this process.

Comment: @SabirKhan 50000 records

Comment: So, what is the stacke trace from the running Java process?

Comment: There doesn't look any problem with your code as such and as per your comments, problem occurs sporadically during heavy load at DB server so issue does look environmental about locking etc by other threads / programs . Does your program remains stuck even after marking all 50k records or during the process of marking?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The problem is that there were no exception during code execution. Is there any way to get additional info what is going on during `pstmt.executeQuery();`?

Comment: @SabirKhan Program stuck even after marking all 50k records

Comment: Show us the **complete** Postgres function and the content of `databaseQueryStringMark`. How many elements does `paramsArray` contain? Is it faster if you do call it through a SQL client? Does it return a result? If yes, why are you not processing the result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I've done it

Comment: Did you check the performance of the `UPDATE` statement (by looking at the execution plan)? It is most probably faster if you get rid of the unnest and the sub-select using: `where id = any("id$arr")`. Did you check if the `UPDATE` was [waiting for a lock](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) when it took so long?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I'll try to change query on `where id = any("id$arr")` and investigate about `waiting for a lock`, but the question is how to force exit my java program after long execution Postgresql function. If to see on my own program logs I could see that statement `pstmt.executeQuery();` started execution but never ended. I couldn't see in logs string _Query for mark bulk data as completed execution completed ..._